# arXiv submission 'On hold' status and primary category changed to 'None'

Tags: arxiv

Recently I've sent a paper to arXiv, to math.GM primary category, then, somehow it was added a crosslist to math.CO, the category I'm not endorsed and can't send there papers, it was done automatically or by moderators. The same day submission was put to 'on hold', this status took approx. 2 days. Then submission category was changed to 'None' and 'Crosslist' to math.CO was removed, see screenshot [submission status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhp9t.png).

Has somebody experienced same situation and what probability that paper Will be rejected/approved?

Comment: As for rejected / approved only the editor can decide - we can’t...

Comment: @PKK Could you update with the outcome of this?

Comment: @GoodDeeds it was rejected after few days. And it was correct decision since article didn't contain anything interesting afterall